# NPM Errors when installing sails.js

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I just did my first install of node.js on a windows 10 machine. I went to install sails.js by npm install sails -g and it is blowing out with the following errors:

```
$ npm install sails -g
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sails" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Invalid name: "@sailshq/express"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\sites\Node\site1\npm-debug.log
```

Any ideas why it is doing this?

EDIT: After uninstalling/reinstalling node I can now install sails.js. When I try to create a project though I get the following errors:

```
$ sails new site1
module.js:487
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@sailshq/lodash'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js:8:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Comment: Although there is a similar issue which was discussed in git in this URL=> https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3984 , I presume it is more or less related to `Node` and `Mac OS` and from your error log, I could see that you are facing this issue in a `Windows` box. I would advise you to uninstall your node.js completely and then to try again (with a latest version of `Node.js` and `npm`)

Comment: It must have been something with my work computer. It installed and ran fine on my home computer.